JavaScript Query Google Sheets API To Retrieve All Sheets
I have the following code to query a single sheet (Sheet1) from a google sheet document. Haven't been able to find any documentation on how to query all sheets from the file
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const spreadsheetId = '123456';

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: "credentials/sheets_token.json",
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
});


const client = await auth.getClient();
const googleSheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: client });

const res = await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    auth,
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    range: 'Sheet1'
});

Tried using empty range, or excluding range parameter, or using range "Sheet1:Sheet10" none worked. Also tried fetching all sheets from the metadata, but you can only get various sheets' titles not their rows data

Modification points:

In your situation, I think that first, it is required to retrieve all sheet names using "Method: spreadsheets.get".
In order to retrieve all values from all sheets by one API call, "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet" is used.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
From:
const res = await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    auth,
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    range: 'Sheet1'
});

To:
// Retrieve all sheet names.
const res1 = await sheets.spreadsheets.get({
  spreadsheetId,
  fields: "sheets(properties(title))",
});

// Retrieve values from all sheets.
const res2 = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
  spreadsheetId,
  ranges: res1.data.sheets.map(({ properties: { title } }) => title),
});
const values = res2.data.valueRanges;

Testing:
When this script is run, values is as follows.
[
  {
    range: '###',
    majorDimension: 'ROWS',
    values: [[,,,],[,,,],,,]
  },
  ,
  ,
  ,
]

Note:

When you have already known your sheet names, you can also use the following script. In this case, please set your sheet names like ranges: ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,],.
const res2 = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
  spreadsheetId,
  ranges: ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,],
});
const values = res2.data.valueRanges;



References:

Method: spreadsheets.get
Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet

